# how to get pairs of elements via jsoup?

Tags: jsoup

Let's say I'm looking for two sibling nodes `A` and `B`. They'll satisfy the selector

```
root.select("A ~ B")
```

and that selector will return all such `B`s.

But what if I need all such `A`/`B` *pairs*? I'm currently doing the following:

```
root.select("A").stream()
        .filter(a -> a.parent() != null)
        .forEach(a -> {
            Element b = a.parent().select("B:gt(" + a.elementSiblingIndex() + ")").first();
            if (b != null) {
                // do something with a and b
            }
        });
```

Is this approximately the right idiom? The `a.parent().select()` seems clunky, but I can't find a simpler way to do it.

Comment: I'm having trouble visualizing this, could you post the full HTML snippet and which element's you're trying to get?

Comment: I've tried to rewrite the question to make it clearer. Sorry about that.

Comment: Also, do I need my second `select` to be `":root > B:gt(" + a.elementSiblingIndex() + ")"`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is anything wrong with your approach. If you don't want to use `a.parent().select()` you could get the same result with `siblingElements()`:

```
root.select("A~B").stream().forEach(b -> {
    List<Element> siblings = b.siblingElements().subList(0, b.elementSiblingIndex());
    Collections.reverse(siblings);
    for (Element a : siblings) {
        if(a.nodeName().equals(B)) break;
        if(a.nodeName().equals(A)){
            // do something with a and b
        }
    }
});
```